# Error MT0014: iOS 6 does not support building applications targeting ARMv6

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xcode4.5

Just upgraded xcode and monodevelop/monotouch to latest versions (see below) and suddenly I get this error when building for the IPhone as target (compiles well for the simulator). I've tried all combinations of setting "Supported architetures" in the project options dialog to ARMv6, ARMv7 and ARMv6 + ARMv7 as well as setting "deployment target" to 5.0, but it doesn't seem to matter - I always get the same error:

```
Error MT0014: iOS 6 does not support building applications targeting ARMv6 (MT0014)
```

MonoDevelop 3.0.4.7
Monotouch: 6.0.2
Mac OS X 10.7.5
Xcode 4.5 (1839)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because Xcode 4.5 does not allow you to build for ARMv6 (the binaries are missing).

You can still build for ARMv6 if you use an older Xcode version (e.g. 4.4). This older version of Xcode can co-exists (side-by-side) with 4.5.

Note that you'll need to change the **SDK location** (inside MD preferences) to point to your Xcode 4.4 installation for this to work properly.

Comment: Oh... and I'm a mac n00b... I'll try to download the old version and see if I can install it side by side then. Cheers.

Comment: You'll need to rename the Xcode.app (e.g. Xcode44.app) before dragging it into /Applications - otherwise it will replace 4.5

Comment: Thanks! Our app no longer needed to support older iOS versions so I could set platform to iOS 5.0 and ARM7 and then it compiled fine. I got compiler error on these settings before too, because I forgot to change the options for a test-project I had in the same solution :/

Comment: Isn't it weird though that a file->new project results in the same error? At least it did on my machine, which made me wonder if my machine had been messed up during the updates :(

Comment: For the current MonoDevelop's templates the default is *still* ARMv6. That default setting will change in future releases.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you really care about ancient devices (armv6  = iPhone 2G/3G, iPod 1G/2G) don't bother with armv6 anymore.

Comment: True! I had to read up on ARMx... the things you learn when working on new platforms... thanks.